# Retrieve value from an arrow function (popmotion's pointer X position)

Tags: javascript, popmotion

I need to store the pointer X position in a variable.
According popmotion documentation ([See link here](https://popmotion.io/api/pointer/)) the following would do the trick:

```
import { pointer } from 'popmotion';
pointer().start(({ x }) => console.log(x));
```

in fact, by using the code above the exact value of *x* is shown in the console, but I am having troubles in using the value in my code.

I have already tried:

```
const X = pointer().start(({ x }) => x);
const X = pointer().start(({ x }) => { return x; });
```

but *console.log(X)* returns *{stop: ƒ}*

I am not very familiar with arrow functions and I appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: `let X; pointer().start(({ x }) => X = x);` but bear in mind that if `start` is asynchronous, `X` will be `undefined` untill `start` finishes its work

Comment: The `.start` callback runs asynchronously, when the cursor moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let x;
 pointer.start(it => x = it.x);
```

Note that `x` will be undefined until `start` calls back.